# Using Git on 2 different computers with OneDrive

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, onedrive

I am using my OneDrive to commit changes to and push updates using VSCode. On my desktop and my laptop I have the same directory within OneDrive opened in my workspace. All the changes are the same and code is identical, but the thing I'm concerned about is if I am working on my desktop it only says I have 1-2 changes to commit (typically the file I'm working on). However, on my laptop even though I'm using the same OneDrive cloud directory it says I have 33 changes to commit. I'm not sure why its showing that. I tried running a git pull in VSCode but it still shows the same 33 changes to commit. I haven't committed anything on my laptop yet as I'm not sure if it will overwrite anything. I just don't understand why the difference even though it's using the same directory on the Cloud. I checked in that directory and I am seeing only one ".git" hidden folder with no other nested ".git" folder inside. Any help would be great, thanks!

Dan

Comment: This sounds dangerous. Why not just commit and push changes on one, then pull on the other to keep working?

Comment: Just a side note, don't use syncing file systems like OneDrive or iCloud or Drive in combination with git repository folders. I wasn't aware that iCloud was syncing my folders and it left me with a headache for days. I would suggest you just work with a remote repository like github and just commit/push your changes whenever you want to continue working on the other workstation

Comment: @SiHa to be honest I'm still learning best practices as I'm just getting started using Git so I never even though of just pulling the changes over on my laptop, thank you for your tip I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @RobrechtVM thats a good tip as well, thank you for that I will just use that going forward. What headache did iCloud leave you with if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Do you guys have any good YouTube or Udemy courses on learning git with VSCode better? I know there's tons out there using the terminal or iTerm2 but in a production environment isn't VSCode ideal to use?

Comment: My .git folder was constantly syncing, i think there were conflicts which weren't resolved correctly resulting in a messed up repository. I would advise to use GitKraken instead of the built-in git feature from VSCode. Have a look it has a free license and I use it for all my personal and professional projects

Comment: I use git with VSCode, too and its great, but beware that it does sometimes get confused, especially on large repo's. On occasion it will say that there are no changes to commit, or even say that there are loads when there are none.  manual git fetch will usually sort this, but I have had to close and re-open VSCode to clear it, a few times.

Comment: @RobrechtVM thank you for explaining that and your recommendation of GitKraken, I have heard about it but haven't researched it yet but I definitely will now, thanks!

Comment: @SiHa wow that is really good to know about large repo's, I will keep that in mind for sure, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put the various warnings in the comments into answer form - this is not a reliable way to share a repo between computers.  You should create a local clone on each computer.  The problem you're experiencing is just one of the minor annoyances that can go wrong - things could (and likely will) get a lot worse if you continue with that approach.

FWIW I suspect the specific problem may have to do with the way git uses file stats to tell where changes might potentially be; but I don't know enough about OneDrive to pin down an exact explanation.

But it doesn't really matter.  Sharing repos between folders is built-in `git` functionality, and you'll be much better served by using it as intended.  Note that if you want, you can create direct links between your two clones so that you don't have to push changes through the origin; or if that isn't convenient to do, you could even use OneDrive to pass `bundle` files back and forth (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)

Those approaches do still require you to commit the changes you share. (Those commits don't have to be on your main branches, and you don't have to keep them, but it is an extra step to sharing them.)  If that's a problem, you could even keep a copy of the working folder (but *not* the entire repo) on OneDrive, and copy updated files back and forth through that copy.  You'd still have to make sure your files sync when appropriate, but it's a less risky option than working directly on the sync'd directory.

Comment: thank you for your answer and breaking it down the way you did. It helped clear a lot of it up! I will absolutely look into all the different approaches you mentioned, thanks again!